# How to create a vcproj with qmake such that its filters reflect the directory structure?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt4, qmake

I use qmake (Qt 4.5.1) to create my vcproj files. I would like to create customized filters for the output vcproj, such that not every *.h file ends up in the "Header Files" filter, *.cpp in "Source Files" etc.

For example, a project containing the files

```
foo\foo.h
foo\foo.cpp
bar\bar.h
bar\bar.cpp
```

should have a vcproj file with

```
foo
   foo.h
   foo.cpp
bar
   bar.h
   bar.cpp
```

instead of

```
Header Files
   bar.h
   bar.cpp
Source Files
   bar.cpp
   foo.cpp
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run qmake with **`CONFIG -= flat`**, you'll get the following project structure:

```
Header Files
    foo
        foo.h
    bar
        bar.h
Source Files
    foo
        foo.cpp
    bar
        bar.cpp
```

This has always bothered me, which is why I'm writing a fix on the Mac for Xcode projects. Eventually I'll probably write one for VS (which is easier since the project file is an XML document).

If you're writing software strictly on Windows using Visual Studio, I would recommend using the [Visual Studio Integration Plugin](http://www.qtsoftware.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in) as it will automatically generate the UIC and MOC steps needed to compile Qt files.