# How to import qt projects in visual c++ 2010?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-addins, visual-c++-2010-express

I developed an application using qtCreator and I figured out that I need to import the project in visual studio. I tried to run the visual studio add-in (1.1.9) but it didn't work. Knowing that I have visual c++ express edition 2010

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: when you say the add-in didn't worked, what was the problem? the add-in is very useful, it will automatically create a VS project using the Makefile (.pro) from the Qt project

Comment: it says the installer could not find an installation of visual studio 200x please note that visual c++ express is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using Qt Add-in a detailed solution can be found at
http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 3):

QMake can generate vcproj out of .pro files. Use those to import into VS.

The option you are looking for is `qmake -tp vc`.

See: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-platform-notes.html

For more info see here: [How to generate .sln/.vcproj using qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339832/how-to-generate-sln-vcproj-using-qmake)
Or: [How to create a vcproj with qmake such that its filters reflect the directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872875/how-to-create-a-vcproj-with-qmake-such-that-its-filters-reflect-the-directory-str)